# Union Join "where" cannot select the data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem using union join to select sql using "where", below is my table.

**first_table**

```html
id | folder | category id | status
1    Peter      5            0
2    John       6            1
3    Shawn      7            0
```

**second_table**

```html
id | filename| category id |status
1    123.sql     9          1
2    you.png    12          1
3    it.pdf     11          0
```

**First table join Second table**

```html
id | folder_filename| category id | status
1    Peter               5            0
2    John                6            1
3    Shawn               7            0
4    123.sql             9            1
5    you.png             12           1
6    it.pdf              11           0
```

I am using this sql to select which status is 0, but can't work.

```html
select f.id, f.folder, f.category_id, f.status
from first_table f
union all
select s.id, s.folder, s.category_id, s.status
from second_table s where f.status = 0;
```

My expected result like below table:

```html
id | folder_filename| category id | status
1    Peter               5            0
2    Shawn               7            0
3    it.pdf              11           0
```

Comment: Just add the `where` clause to the first subquery as well as the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions :

```
select f.id, f.folder, f.category_id, f.status
from first_table f where f.status = 0
union all
select s.id, s.folder, s.category_id, s.status
from second_table s where s.status = 0;
```

OR

```
select * from (
select f.id, f.folder, f.category_id, f.status
from first_table f
union all
select s.id, s.folder, s.category_id, s.status
from second_table s) temp 
where temp.status = 0;
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the second version. It can't make use of an index on `status`, and has to merge bigger intermediate tables.

Comment: Just the first solution can work.